# Every day,week,month,year in AppEngine cron (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I'm trying to set an appengine task to be repeated at midnight of every day, week, month, and year, for clearing a high score list for a game.

My cron.yaml looks like this:

```
- description: daily clear
  url: /delete?off=10
  schedule: every day 00:00
- description: weekly clear
  url: /delete?off=20
  schedule: every monday 00:00
- description: monthly clear
  url: /delete?off=30
  schedule: every month 00:00
- description: yearly clear
  url: /delete?off=40
  schedule: every year 00:00
```

Daily and weekly jobs are OK, but I can't figure out how to make a job repeat every month and year. This is [the schedule format](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html#The_Schedule_Format).

For each month job, I've tried expressions like 'every month', '1st of month', etc, but nothing did work. Is this type of schedule possible in cron jobs?

Or do I need to just invoke the clearing page just daily at 00:00, and do this logic in page and test current date, if it's the start of week/month/year?

Comment: If it repeats every day, it also repeats every week, month, quarter, and year.  And it repeats each full moon, also.  What's wrong with making the daily job check for "Sunday" or the 1st of the Month?

Comment: It occurs only once each week.  A weekly job which runs on Sunday repeats each week.

Comment: thanks, sorry. Week starts on Monday here.

Comment: +1 Nice. Saved me a lot of time digging through documentation

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The docs you link to give examples of how you could achieve all of the results you want.

```
# Daily:
every day 00:00

# Weekly:
every monday 00:00

# Monthly:
1 of month 00:00

# Yearly:
1 of jan 00:00
```

Comment: @Robert uhm, are you sure? I don't think "1 of month" is a valid syntax.

Comment: @systempuntoout Yes, I'm sure '1 of month' is valid.  It specifies that the job should run on '01 Jan', '01 Feb', ..., '01 Dec', and so on.  The docs use that syntax as well, though typically in a list such as '1,15 of month'.

Comment: @Robert ("every"|ordinal) (days) ["of" (monthspec)] (time), it looks it requires an ordinal

Comment: @systempuntoout From about four lines below where you copied that:  'monthspec [...] You can also say "month" to mean every month, as in "1,8,15,22 of month 09:00".'

Comment: @Robert you are right :), it's reported in the spec; it's weird because it does not follow the ("every"|ordinal) syntax specified above.

Comment: @systempuntoout I found it odd too; but I checked I had checked it, and it worked right. ;)

Comment: @RobertKluin   What id I want to run it every alternate friday ?

Answer (score 3):

I would go with something like this:

```
- description: daily clear
  url: /delete/daily
  schedule: every day 00:00
- description: weekly clear
  url: /delete/weekly
  schedule: every monday 00:00
- description: monthly clear
  url: /delete/monthly
  schedule: first of month 00:00
- description: yearly clear
  url: /delete/yearly
  schedule: first of jan 00:00
```

AFAIK you can't use a syntax like this `/delete?off=30` in `yaml` but you need to define a route explicitly for every different clear with `/delete/weekly` for example

Comment: This doesn't work. Using `first of month 00:00` gives the error `Unable to assign value 'first of month 00:00' to attribute 'schedule'`, but using `1 of month` works fine.