# Google Cloud cron.yaml Intervals

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron, gcloud, cron-task

I'm trying to customise a cronjob to schedule run a function in Google Cloud.
I've been reading the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref)
and as per title, one thing confuses me.

The documentation mentions that `every` prefix must be used if the function is to be repeated at a `DAILY` interval. But it is not clear on how it works if you want a function to be repeated at a `WEEKLY`, `MONTHLY`, or in my specific case, `YEARLY` intervals.

I've added `schedule: 1 of jan 00:10` to my cron.yaml, am I correct to assume that this will be repeated every 1st of January, 10 minutes after midnight or will it only run once? Do I need to change it to `schedule: every 1 of jan 00:10` ?

For the record, I found a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521385/every-day-week-month-year-in-appengine-cron-python) on SO, but the problem is said question was asked and answered **10 years ago**, so I dont know how applicable it still is.

Comment: This is still applicable: [Every day,week,month,year in AppEngine cron (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521385/every-day-week-month-year-in-appengine-cron-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is like you said, `schedule: 1 of jan 00:10` will work for you. It will be repeated on 1st of Jan every year at 12:10 am.

Similarly, to run weekly: `schedule: every monday 00:00`

Monthly: `schedule: 1 of month 09:00`

For more such examples and verification you can refer to “Custom interval” section in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#formatting_the_schedule)

Comment: If I added ```every``` to the month and year; eg. ```schedule: every 1 of month 09:00```, is there any difference?

Comment: If you try to add ‘every’ for month and year as well, you will get this error: “INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cron jobs only support Groc format for schedule”. So I suggest you not add it and keep it simple as provided in the document. Hope it helps :)